# Widget similar to Xamarin.Android popup menu, for Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, popupmenu

Is there any widget, similar to Xamarin.Android **popup menu**, for **Xamarin.Forms** (especially for Android + iOS)?

Like in the image on this link:
[Android popup menu in listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcYIp.png)

I've already achieved those **three dots** button for each row, but I'm looking for some UI widget/component, that could be shown on similar position - it will be shown beside those "three dots" button.

Any luck?

Comment: Typically in Xamarin.Forms a context action would be used on your `ListView` to do something somewhat similar as shown in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity#Context_Actions). Otherwise, you'd have to write your own custom control or renderer specifically to create that look.

Comment: @Nick It's not exactly what I need. I need same UI for menu items as in the picture I mentioned. Means that the menu should open/appear beside the three dot image/button. Not on the top toolbar. I need only that much customization.

Answer (score 0):

Set your list, and custom frame Control
https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup